# How to pick image from gallery and upload to server (parse.com) ?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hi I m using Eclipse and new to Android.
Is there a simple way to pick image and upload it to parse.com server.
also, is is there is a simple way to retrieve image from server and set this image to a ImageView on layout.

Comment: Both can be done relatively easily, do you already have the image picking implemented in your app?

Comment: Your question is already answered on stackoverflow. Use search tool to find out.

Comment: take a look at this SO Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852110/parse-com-android-how-do-i-save-images-to-my-parse-database-so-that-i-can-use?rq=1

Comment: My suggestion is, Before posting here first try your self.... and take help with @StackOverFlow ( previous post ). Still if you facing any problem ... then come here and post ur problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to this way for pickup image from camera & gallery.

```
// this is local variable.
String selectedImagePath, ServerUploadPath = "" + "", str_response;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";
static File mediaFile;
private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video
```

this method for camera & Gallery image pick up.

```
public void cameraAndGalaryPicture() {
    final String[] opString = { "Take Photo", "Choose From Gallery",
            "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder dbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dbuilder.setTitle("Add Photo!");

    dbuilder.setItems(opString, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (opString[which].equals("Take Photo")) {
                fromCamera();
            } else if (opString[which].equals("Choose From Gallery")) {
                fromFile();
            } else {
                // Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                // .load(R.drawable.default_image).resize(360, 200)
                // .into(iv_Profile_pic);
                rotatedBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.default_image);
                Global.mImage = rotatedBMP;
                Log.e("Else if", "msg::19th Feb- " + rotatedBMP);
                Log.e("Else if", "msg::19th Feb- " + Global.mImage);
                // dialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    });

    dbuilder.show();
}

public void fromCamera() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

}

public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    Log.e("path", "media file:-" + mediaFile);
    return mediaFile;
}

public void fromFile() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
            SELECT_PICTURE);
}

public String getPath(Uri uri, Activity activity) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = activity
            .managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

this method for compress image

```
private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {

        int targetW = 380;
        int targetH = 800;
        Log.d("Get w", "width" + targetW);
        Log.d("Get H", "height" + targetH);
        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor << 1;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath,
                bmOptions);

        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();

        try {

            File imageFile = new File(selectedImagePath);

            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                    imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            Log.e("Orintation", "  :-" + orientation);
            switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:

                mtx.postRotate(270);
                rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                        bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
                    bitmap.recycle();
                iv_Profile_pic.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
                Global.edtImage = rotatedBMP;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:

                mtx.postRotate(180);
                rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                        bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
                    bitmap.recycle();
                iv_Profile_pic.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
                Global.edtImage = rotatedBMP;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:

                mtx.postRotate(90);
                rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                        bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
                    bitmap.recycle();
                iv_Profile_pic.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
                Global.edtImage = rotatedBMP;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:

                mtx.postRotate(0);
                rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                        bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
                    bitmap.recycle();
                iv_Profile_pic.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
                Global.edtImage = rotatedBMP;
                break;
            default:
                mtx.postRotate(0);
                rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                        bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
                    bitmap.recycle();
                iv_Profile_pic.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
                // img_profilepic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                // .decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath));
                Global.edtImage = rotatedBMP;

            }

            Log.i("RotateImage", "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                    Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            // hear store data in parse table.
            ParseFile ParseimageFile1 = new ParseFile("IMG_" + timeStamp
                    + ".jpg", data);
            ParseimageFile1.saveInBackground();
            // ParseimageFile1 variable declare at Globle

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this is on activity result.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            Log.d("select pah", "path" + selectedImagePath);
            previewCapturedImage();
        }

    }
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
            selectedImagePath = mediaFile.toString();
            previewCapturedImage();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

}
```

now store data at parse table like.
and after store fetch data

```
ParseObject obj = new ParseObject("ClassName");
    obj.put("table colum name", ParseimageFile1);
    obj.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                // success
            } else {
                // fail
            }
        }
    });

    // now get image from parse table
    // in parse table image data type is parseFile

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
            "Class Name");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                // success
                for (ParseObject parseObject : list) {
                    ParseFile image = (ParseFile) parseObject
                            .get("key_name");
                    Log.e(key_TAG, "get Image URL " + image.getUrl());
                }
            } else {
                // fail
            }

        }
    });
```